# How to generate random number with dot?

Tags: vb.net, decimal

I have classic integer generator of random numbers.

But I need a random number from 0 to three decimal numbers after the first, the smallest is 0.010 and biggest 9.910.

> Example: **0.136** *OR* **1.539**

My code function is this:

```
 Public Function RandomWtring(len As Integer) As String
        Dim chars = "0123456789"
        Dim str_len = len
        Dim randomstring = ""

        For i As Integer = 0 To len - 1
            Dim rNum = Math.Floor(Rnd() * chars.Length)
            randomstring += chars.Substring(rNum, 1)
        Next

        Return randomstring
    End Function
```

But I dont know how to do the **0.254** example... thx

Comment: So you probably want a random number and divide it by 1000.

Comment: @HansPassant yes exactly

Comment: @PavelRakowski What is `len` for?

Comment: @AndrewMorton hahah I dont know i just found the code on internet and im trying to use few samples for myself as i cant code better so i dont know but i need number generator what will be always different on click so 0.001 then 1.025 then 2.321 etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random number generators (RNGs) usually produce a number in the range zero up to (but not including) another number. To generate a random number in a range from min to max, you need to get the size of the range, use the RNG, then scale that back into the desired range.

The VB.NET Rnd() function is not actually a very good RNG; the .NET [Random Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8) is a bit better (there are better in some aspects, but let's not worry about that for this question). All RNGs need some sort of initialisation to start them off, so what you will need to do is have the line

```
Dim rand As New Random()
```

somewhere in your code outside the actual function:

```
Function MyRandomNumber() As String
    Dim min As Decimal = 0.01D
    Dim max As Decimal = 9.91D
    Dim decimalPlaces = 3
    Dim multiplier = CDec(Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces))

    Dim range = (max - min) * multiplier
    Dim val = rand.Next(0, CInt(range + 1))
    Return (val / multiplier + min).ToString()

End Function
```

I used variables for the minimum and maximum values, and the number of decimal places needed, just in case you need to change them. Also, it is good programming practise to used appropriately-named variables for things like that so that it is easier to understand what is going on if you go back to the code after a few months.

---

If you need a number rather than a string, change the declaration to

```
Function MyRandomNumber() As Decimal
```

and the return line to

```
    Return val / multiplier + min
```

Comment: @PavelRakowski *"I dont know but i tried to use it but still return 0. I called this random in my code like this: Dim literNum = MyRandomNumber() and still 0 Am I doing something wrong?"* I suggest that you make a new Console Application just to test the code in to confirm it does what you want. (I did test it myself.) Then you can have a look at your program to see if you can find out why it isn't working as intended.

Comment: you absolutelly right! I dont know why in my mess app it not generate but i did clean app and button and yes it works perfect! I LOVE YOU! :D

Comment: how do I get this value inside or composed url? I have other code and i tried to add this inside but it doesnt return the same

Comment: @PavelRakowski That should be a new question. Show how you're composing the URL, the desired result and the actual result, and I'm sure someone will be along to help. (However, something like `myUrl = "https://example.com/index.aspx?x=" & literNum` should be fine.)

Comment: ok i will try more and if i cant i will ask new question; how ever this literNum i use in other funcion so call other function in other is not normal way i suppose

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Rnd() * upperLimit`. It will generate decimal random numbers and then you can round it using `Math.Round` method to any decimal places you like.

`Math.Floor` converts number to integer (bigget integer below given number).

Comment: While this is the sensible way to do this, if OP wants to keep his leading zero this won't work like his current algorithm, while AndrewMorton's answer will. If that's significant.

Comment: @laancelot non of solution work I tried once it gives me 0.835 but after just adding 9 or only 0 lol

Comment: @laancelot btw it keeps rotating only 4 random numbers not always random its strange

Comment: @laancelot I found in the code this:  Dim st3 = RandomWtring(3) so does it help? Im not sure how to get rid of this but certainly there is also len somewhere i will need to dig if it heps